# rarely, apc_fetch does not return existing key

Tags: php, apc

I noticed the following symptoms:
One the first http request, the user performs some action that invokes apc_store(somekey, somevalue). In ALL cases, the store operation returns TRUE.

On a subsequent http request, only a few seconds later, apc_fetch is performed, for the previously stored value. The key is the same, of course.

On rare occasions, the apc_fetch returns FALSE. For example, in our production environment, 5 out of 540 requests returned FALSE.

Any ideas how to diagnose this?

tnx

Comment: do you have only 1 server or more?

Comment: already got my answer in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720993/php-apc-not-working-with-some-chars-in-key