# PHP APC not working with some chars in key?

Tags: php, caching, apc, zend-server-ce

I have a few test installments of zend server CE (php5.3), one on Mac 10.8.2, one on Linux EC2 instance, both using the default APC implementation (zend data cache) that comes with the installation.

On both machines, I call:

```
apc_store("Installation:1234:lastActivity", "x", 120);
```

Then I call apc_fetch for that key.
On the Mac, apc_fetch works.
On the Linux, apc_fetch returns FALSE and fails.

Now for the weird stuff on the Linux box, a few tests I made:
1. If I remove the last char in the key (y), apc_fetch works.
2. If I change the colon (:) to slash (/), apc_fetch works.

Any ideas what is going on?
thanks...

Comment: check you php.ini / apc.ini setting "apc.filters", see if your linux instance has filters.

Comment: on neither the mac nor the linux is there any apc entry in php.ini. I was unable to find apc.ini, probably because the cache impl is zend cache - not apc, but zend cache uses the apc_xxx interface...

Comment: ok, did you do a simply test, using very common key, like apc_store('somekey', 'somevalue') without any special characters. using string only. does it work on both machines? for the ini setting, you can search "apc.filters" on php.in. my EC2 instance, if you are using yum to install, my apc.ini stored in /etc/php.d/apc.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend Server doesn't actually use APC, instead using it's own implementation - the "Zend Data Cache". There appear to be some subtle differences between them.

One thing that the ZDC has is 'namespaces', where you prefix a key with a '{name}::', and then you can remove all keys that start with that prefix.

It may be that there is a bug when there are two (non consecutive) colons in the string. In the meantime, it's easy enough to simply tweak the structure of the key to avoid the problem.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware that namespaces create key name constraints... anyway, I switched to '/' instead of ':' and it works for now :)